# Can "cap deploy:setup" destroy BASH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, capistrano

I had a problem this morning deploying an application with capistrano.

```
# git push
# cap deploy:setup
```

Something strange happened and than I wasn't able to ssh to my host anymore.

Technical staff says (in Italian): "the commands you have run overwrote the shell binaries causing the system to be no more usable". Two options: I am a stupid, or they are wrong.
Here's the shell output on *cap:deploy* and then the error on ssh. Once the system (VPS) has been rebooted, I wasn't able to ssh anymore.

Any ideas?

```
mattia@desktop:/var/www/rails/my_application$ git push
Counting objects: 239, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (191/191), done.
Writing objects: 100% (202/202), 379.77 KiB, done.
Total 202 (delta 44), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://mattia@my_application.it/~/git/my_application.git
   96c1f19..3cc9e1c  master -> master
mattia@desktop:/var/www/rails/my_application$ cap deploy:setup
  * executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/rails/my_application /var/www/rails/my_application/releases /var/www/rails/my_application/shared /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/system /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/log /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/pids &&  chmod g+w /var/www/rails/my_application /var/www/rails/my_application/releases /var/www/rails/my_application/shared /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/system /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/log /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/pids"
    servers: ["beta.my_application.it"]
    [beta.my_application.it] executing command
 ** [out :: beta.my_application.it]
 ** [out :: beta.my_application.it] malloc: ../bash/parse.y:2823: assertion botched
 ** [out :: beta.my_application.it] nunits < 30
 ** [out :: beta.my_application.it] Aborting...
    command finished
failed: "env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1 sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/rails/my_application /var/www/rails/my_application/releases /var/www/rails/my_application/shared /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/system /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/log /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/pids &&  chmod g+w /var/www/rails/my_application /var/www/rails/my_application/releases /var/www/rails/my_application/shared /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/system /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/log /var/www/rails/my_application/shared/pids'" on beta.my_application.it
mattia@desktop:/var/www/rails/my_application$ ssh beta.my_application.it
Linux my_application 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5.028stab079.2ent #1 SMP Fri Dec 17 19:44:51 MSK 2010 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Feb  7 12:00:53 2011 from dynamic-adsl-xx-xx-xx-xx.------.------.it

malloc: ../bash/subst.c:4494: assertion botched
realloc: called with unallocated block argument
Aborting...Connection to beta.my_application.it closed.
```

Comment: Could you post your deploy.rb file?

Comment: It turns out that Capistrano wasn't responsible of bash corruption. Looks like I am not a stupid. When I asked the service provider the third time *how* could the commands above overwrite bash, the problem was fixed with no explanation and everything got back perfectly working. I suppose there was a different problem like filesystem corruption or openvz misconfiguration / config file corruption.

Comment: Given the lack of knowledge from those system administrators, I would look for another hosting solution. Since who knows what they might accidentally delete or "fix".

Answer (score 2):

The short-answer is no, unless you have other plugins that aren't standard, or someone gave you a messed up Gem. (Almost nobody bothers to validate the gem signatures.) The standard deploy:setup only creates a couple of symlinks, and directories.

It does run as `root`, and in theory if you were to set your variables to values (untested) such as `set :deploy_to, '/bin/bash'`, it *may* damage the binary, but unless you did that, I'd say that's a non-issue.

You can debug this, without relying on a shell - by using SSH in command mode:

```
# ssh myuser@myserver -c 'history'
```

Which will dump out the history file (bash) of that user, so you can test if there's been any tampering on the server, you can also check it as root, and/or run commands such as `who`, `last` and other one-liners which give you back logs (you can also `cat /var/log/messages` and look for suspicious activity.

I'd say that the chance of Capistrano being responsible for this is 0 (Source: I'm the maintainer.) - but you can probably get your system back into a working state using the SHS command mode, as I mentioned above (`ssh myuser@myserver -c 'aptitude install bash --force'` for example)

A word to the wise, if you never figure out how this happened, erase the server and change your passwords… just use this as a method to get things back up and running. It's not a very subtle tactic, but if you've been hacked, a hacker could easily throw you out by making a user which uses an alternative shell, and corrupting yours.

It would also be a huge help from your admins, if they could give you `/bin/bash` - the contents of the file, so you can see if it's text, junk, corrupted binary, or something from your deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information above, big Maintainer! The unknown problem has been solved by the system provider with no explanation, and **wasn't related to Capistrano** (see the comment above your answer). I can't figure out how that happened, I would say due to service provider incompetence. Anyway, I checker root's history and there was nothing strange. Hope I'll never need **ssh -c** but I'm goin to take a look at thin option's documentation. Thanks again!